# LEAFLET GEOMAN - Picking up the coordinates inside this polygon draw

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I already have a geojson being consulted and that is plotting these black dots. And then I inserted the leaflet-geoman plugin to give users the freedom to create polygons on the map. Basically draw something there.

[image: leaflet-geoman draw]

For example: Draw a polygon to get only the information inside that polygon.

When using the tool to draw a polygon on the map I wanted to get which black dot is inside the drawing.

[image: polygon draw]

in short: I have 4 points within my polygon drawing (which does not come from a geojson, the person draws) and I want to get the information from those points that are within that drawn polygon. Each black dot in this one has an id, and I want to know what points are within the space that the person drew.

My geoman-Leaflet code:

```
      map.pm.addControls({
        position: 'topright',
        // drawCircle: false,
        drawMarker: false,
        drawCircleMarker: false,
        drawRectangle: false,
        cutPolygon: false,
        editPolygon: false,
      });
```

My black dots on the map code:

```
 wellheads.forEach(function (d) {
        d.LatLng = new L.latLng(d.latitude, d.longitude);
      });

  const groupWells = g
        .selectAll('g')
        .data(wellheads)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'visible');

      const points = groupWells
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class', d => {
          if (wellState.selectedWell.guid === d.wellboreGUID) {
            return 'redW';
          } else {
            return 'blackW';
          }
        })
        .attr('id', d => `id-${d.wellboreGUID}`)
        .attr('r', d => {
          if (wellState.selectedWell.guid === d.wellboreGUID) {
            return 1.7;
          } else {
            return 1.0;
          }
        })
```

Comment: That looks like D3. Are you using D3?

Comment: This also looks suspiciously similar to a question from a few days ago (which saw the response "turf.inside"). Is this some kind of college assignment?

Comment: Yup: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383547/picking-up-the-coordinates-inside-this-polygon-draw And it was answerd, but I think the OP don't understand it

Comment: @IvanSanchez yes!

Comment: @IvanSanchez yes was for d3 haha not about college. it's for a task in my job

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cross-post of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383547/picking-up-the-coordinates-inside-this-polygon-draw

Comment: but there's a way that i can gave to the user the freedom to draw a polygon? @IvanSanchez

Comment: Create a working demo on jsfiddle and I show it to you. It is no problem, that the polygon is custom drawn